# Jquery fadein fadeout banner slider

Tags: jquery, html

I have banners for the offer and they are coming dynamically. Want I want to do is to show them one by one i.e first the banner 1 will display then that fades out and another banner display and then thats fade out and so on. I am not getting how to do that. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can u plz show us what u have tried so far ?

Comment: Post your code please and if it possible create a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: since you have already done that,just add fade in (few seconds) in your slide changing line of code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are thousands (yes that much) plugins available to achieve this. My personal favorite is [NivoSlider](http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/). (Not affiliated in any way with them...)

Here are some others too:

- http://responsiveslides.com/
- http://www.basic-slider.com/
- http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/
- http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/02/animated-responsive-image-grid/
- http://wowslider.com/
- ...